# how to secure img src path when user clicks on view source using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to secure the src path of the image when clicks on inspect element so that user should not get to know about the actual src path..please help me with the solution and it should be done with javascript only no other tags should be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert image into base 64 data URIs for embedding images.

Use: http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/

Code sample:

```
.sprite {
  background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA... etc );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly done server-side, where you have an endpoint that serves the image file to you as bytes...

You can store the images in a private location on the server where IIS/`<your favourite web server>` doesn't have direct access to it, but only a web app, running on it, with the required privilege is authorized to do so.

Alternatively people also "store" the images in the database itself and load it directly from there.

In either case, the response which has to be sent back has to be a stream of bytes with the correct mime type.

### Edit:

Here are a couple of links to get you started if you are into ASP.NET:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34084/Generic-Image-Handler-Using-IHttpHandler
- http://aspalliance.com/1322_Displaying_Images_in_ASPNET_Using_HttpHandlers.5 `<-` this sample actually does it from a database.

Don't let the choice of front-end framework (asp.net, php, django, etc) hinder you. Search for similar techniques in your framework of choice.

### Edit:

Another way if you think html5 canvas is shown here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/

However you run into the same problem. Someone can view the image url if they can see the page source. You'll have to revert to the above approach eventually.

Comment: I only have asp.net articles for now. You can search or ask around for similar stuff for your favourite framework.